# Grab specific Excel file name when iterating over folders using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to pull an Excel spreadsheet called 'Apples.xlsx' from many folders.  However, there is another Excel spreadsheet within each of these same folders, 'Bananas.xlsx'.  When iterating over my folders, I am only pulling the 'Bananas.xlsx' file when really I only want the 'Apples.xlsx' file.  I have tried specifying the 'Apples.xlsx' file like this:

```
import os

directory = os.fsencode("mydir")

for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if ((filename.endswith('.xlsx')) and (filename == 'Apples.xlsx')):
        filenames.append(filename)
filenames.sort()
```

Why isn't it pulling my 'Apples.xlsx' files?

Comment: Look into `glob()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to indent your `if block` so it will be inside your `inner for loop`. I suspect that what happens is that the `inner for loop` finishes, so only the last value of `file` will be checked by your `if block`, which is if alphabetically arranged, would be your 'Bananas.xlsx'

```
import os

directory = os.fsencode("mydir")

for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if ((filename.endswith('.xlsx')) and (filename == 'Apples.xlsx')):
            filenames.append(filename)
filenames.sort()
```